# Java - How to store previous value of String and compare it with current value

Tags: java, string

Lets say I have a String variable called `read`. This variable is getting the value from the user input, saved in another class and prints the value.
If in the second time the same value is given I don't want it to be printed.
I did some thing like this, but it does not work.

```
private String pmsg;

String read = GlobalState.getmsg();

boolean pch = read.equals(pmsg);

if (!pch) {
    pmsg = new String(read);
    System.out.println(read);
}
```

It appears that whenever `read` changes, `pmsg` also changes, hence it will not print as `pch` is always true.  I want store the previous value of the String and compare it with the current value of the String. How do I do this in Java?

Comment: It is difficult to tell from your question what your problem is. Can you provide some additional information on what your program is doing? The above code is not valid Java.

Comment: Explain how `read` changes `pmsg`?

Comment: my java program reads udp packets

Comment: In my java program  one thread reads udp packets as follows;   String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());  and save it in another class which I call globalstate class as follows; GlobalState.setmsg(msg);     Another thread reads it as shown in my original post. Programs works if I don't have  the condition to check but I need that condition.

Comment: You can try storing the values read in some hashing structure and then check against this structure whether the current value read is already present or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. Setmsg() and getmsg() are in two separate threads in a while(true) loop.  All I did was to add following statements to both while loops; Thread.sleep(500);

```
          class  MThread extends Thread {

    private DatagramSocket dsocket; 


        public void run() {
            try {
                   int port = 8888;
                   // Create a socket to listen on the port.
                     dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                   // Create a buffer to read datagrams into.
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[30000];
                   // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
                   DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                    while (true) {
                               try {
                                      // Wait to receive a datagram
                                       dsocket.receive(packet);
                                      //Convert the contents to a string,
                                      String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());



                                      GlobalState.setmsg(msg);

                                       // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
                                         packet.setLength(buffer.length);
                                         Thread.sleep(500); 


                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                       dsocket.close();
                                        break; }
                                  }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  dsocket.close();  e.printStackTrace();}

        }

 }


class PThread extends Thread {


private String pmsg;
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (true) {
                    try {

                       String read = GlobalState.getmsg();



                     //  boolean rdch;
                        boolean pch= read.equals(pmsg);

                       if(!pch)
                       {
                          pmsg =new String(read);
                           System.out.println(read);

                        }

                       Thread.sleep(500);


                      } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("error");
                    e.printStackTrace();}

        } //while

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}        
        }         


 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would set your `pmsg` at the end of your code. Something like this should accomplish what you are looking for (Also notice how I included the `String.equals()` check in the `if` statement so you do not have to create a `boolean`).

```
//Declare variables
private String pmsg = null; //You should probably set this to null so even if your first read is "" it will still print
private String read;

//Method to read and print message
public void readMessage(){
    read = GlobalState.getmsg();

    if (!read.equals(pmsg)){  //Checks if read is the same as the previous message
        System.out.println(read);
    }

    pmsg = read;  //Cache previous message
}
```

Hope this helps.